# Voltage difference in an experiment

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage

I have a question about measuring voltage across two resistor in series.

I used 2 resistors with 1 Mega Ohm and the voltage supply 5 Volt, but I got $V_1=3.2, V_2=1.6V$. There is a big gap between both of them. What happened?

Is there any kind of possibilities that causes this big differences? I need some enlightenment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a hint, read the specifications of your voltmeter carefully.

Comment: I don't think it is the voltmeter problem? Since I used electric one and the first trial was fine

Comment: Consider what would happen if your voltmeter had a resistance of 1MΩ ...

Comment: Ummm, isn't it gonna be just fine?

Comment: Did you bother to measure the resistance of the two 1 M resistors?

Comment: @ThePhoton The input impedance of the VM relative to the load will impact the total voltage drop across the series resistors, but that wouldn't explain the big difference between the voltages across the two resistors in series, right?

Comment: @JohnRennie See my comment to ThePhoton

Comment: Or, on EE SE: [Can a voltmeter itself disturb the exact measuring of voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/514492/6334).

Comment: @BobD, I'm guessing that they didn't measure each voltage drop individually. Instead they measured one of the voltages and subtracted from the supply voltage to determine the other one. If they had measured the drops separately they wouldn't have added up to so close to 5.0 V. (But the guess that one or the other resistor is faulty is also reasonable)

Comment: @ThePhoton Then we need clarification from the OP

Comment: @Kadal Did you measure each voltage drop individually, or did you measure one of the voltages and subtract it from the supply voltage to determine the other one?

Comment: Yes, I didn't measure each $V_1$ and $V_2$ individually. I measured the V2  and subtracted from the supply voltage. Does this affect?

Comment: You said that there was a "big gap" between the resistors in the second experiment.  What did you expect to happen?  Also, what are the resistances of each resistor in each experiment?

Comment: I expect that both of the resistors will have around 2.5V each. The resistors are 1 mega ohm each

Comment: Re, "...does this affect?" Of course it does. You only _measured_ the voltage across one of the two resistors. If your instrument gave a wrong reading, then the value that you _calculated_ for the other resistor must be wrong by the equal and opposite amount.

Comment: No, what will happen if I use 1 mega ohm to an electric voltmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your answer to my comment requesting clarification, you indicated that you didn't measure the voltage drops individually but measured $V_2$ and then subtracted that from 5 volts to get the other drop. You asked if that affected the results.

The answer is yes and the degree of the effect will depend on the input resistance of the voltmeter relative to the resistance of the load.

For example, let's say the VM input resistance is $1M\Omega$. Let the galvanometer resistance be negligible. This puts the $1M\Omega$ VM resistance in parallel with the $1M\Omega$ load resistor, for an effective resistance of $0.5M\Omega$. Now we have a voltage divider and the voltage measured across the one resistor becomes (neglecting any voltage source resistance) 5 x 0.5/(0.5+1) = 1.67 volts. Subtracting that from 5 volts gives you 3.33 volts for the other resistor. These values are comparable with yours, suggesting the VM input resistance is about $1M\Omega$.

Hope this helps.